# How Run two xslt transformations for same node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My xml and xslt file looks like follow. problem is when i apply my transformation file only 2nd one happens 1st one skips. How could i run both on first run. Please help Thanks.

```
//BEFORE TRANSFORMATION 

<A>
 <B>
  <Name>ThisOne</Name>
  <Target>abc</Target>
 </B>
</A>
```

My XSLT FIle

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <!--Transformation 1 to replace Target Text-->
  <xsl:template match="A/B/Target/text()">
    <xsl:text>xyz</xsl:text>  
  </xsl:template>

 <!--Transformation 2 to Add a new node after Target-->
  <xsl:template match="A/B/Target">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <JOJO></JOJO>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What i would like to see after transformation is following

```
<A>
 <B>
  <Name>ThisOne</Name>
  <Target>xyz</Target>
  <JOJO/>
 </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="A/B/Target">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <JOJO></JOJO>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="A/B/Target">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <JOJO></JOJO>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one template to rewrite the B node. Replace those two templates with this:

```
<xsl:template match ="A/B">
    <B>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></Name>
        <Target>xyz</Target>
        <JOJO/>
    </B>
</xsl:template>
```